# My 65W laptop does charge using USB-C only but is the computer slower because of that?

Tags: docking-station, usb-c, throttling

I use my laptop (Dell Inspiron 5480) both as a mobile device and as a desktop replacement. At home I hook up a USB keyboard, mouse, USB DAC, as well as ethernet and HDMI cables to it. Getting a docking station is a no brainer.

I bought a Dell WD15 docking station that connects to the laptop with USB-C and which uses its own 130W power brick. When I connect the docking station to the laptop using the USB-C cable the laptop "thinks" it's plugged in or at least that's what windows shows in the power settings.

My laptop's manufacturer website shows the USB-C port is 5GBPs and "PD" (power delivery). The laptop came with a 65W power brick.
I am aware that if you underpower a laptop it throttles or does not work as well as when using a manufacturer-provided power adapter. Is there a way to determine if my laptop works slower because it's hooked up only using the USB-C? I know USB-C can provide up to 100W of power but I'm not sure my laptop is capable of handling that and I'm not sure if the docking station can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that if you underpower a laptop it throttles or does not work as well as when using a manufacturer-provided power adapter. Is there a way to determine if my laptop works slower because it's hooked up only using the USB-C?

Laptops are primary powered by battery.

If you connect your computer to the docking station and the battery is charging when you use it that means everything is fine.

If the battery is discharging despite being connected that means your laptop doesn't get enough power. (but still it can work with full performance, you need to run tests on your own to determine that).

Comment: Thanks! As a matter of fact, it's the 'full performance' I'm most worried about. How can I test power adapter vs docking station performance?

Comment: run something like FurMark at the same time as Prime95, that will load up both the graphics and CPU. If it is still charging then your laptop is using less power than your brick provides.

Comment: So what matters here is not the perceived performance (which might just be my impression) but rather the fact the battery may not be fully charged after a test?

Comment: Pretty much. As long as the charger can supply enough to power the laptop and let it charge then it's fine, and arguably charging the battery slightly slower might be better for the long term battery health and result in slightly lower temperatures. Anything other than that is window dressing and there is unlikely to be any difference in actual performance of the laptop itself.